# fb sort comments in reverse order based on timestamp

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

In fb Graph Api Explorer how to sort comments by timestamp in reverse chronological order. Fetched comments using object_id/comments
tried using object_id/comments?summary=true&order=chronological as described [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/object/comments).But result is same.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the parameter filter=stream.